# In app purchase + redeem points as gift vouchers

Tags: ios-appstore

We are developing a multiplayer game in which user has to buy some credit point through in app purchase, then he can multiply those points by winning multiplayer challenges with friends. On reaching a certain level of points, he can reward himself by re-deeming gift vouchers (amazon, ebay, etc) through those points. Does apple allow this type of game structure? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Contact App Review

Only Apple's reviewers can answer your question authoritatively. Contact [Apple App Review](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/) and ask them directly.

### App Store Review Guidelines

You can get a feel for what Apple will accept, see [Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). In particular read **Section 3.2**:

> ### 3.2 Other Business Model Issues
>
> The lists below are not exhaustive, and your submission may trigger a change or update to our policies, but here are some additional do’s and don’ts to keep in mind:
>
> ...
>
> (iv) Wallet passes can be used to make or receive payments, transmit offers, or offer identification (such as movie tickets, coupons, and VIP credentials). Other uses may result in the rejection of the app and the revocation of Wallet credentials.
>
> ...